# Second onclick event not working ( first do some changes, second one need to undo them)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have a problem with `onclick` event.

I have two of them in my code and first one is going fine, but the second one which is very similar not work at all.

I'm not sure, if I'm calling `parent` and `siblings` in second function correctly, but I need to affect them somehow using `.cancel`

Here is [my page](https://pawcio93.github.io/PortfolioSinglePage/).

And here is script:

```
$(window).ready(updateHeight);
$(window).resize(updateHeight);
$(window).resize(updateHeight2);

// update hobby containers height when resize
function updateHeight() {
  var div = $('.hobby');
  var width = div.width();
  div.css('height', width);
}
// update hobbyOnClick containers height when resize
function updateHeight2() {
  var div = $('.hobbyOnClick');
  var width = 0.7262 * div.width();
  div.css('height', width);
}


// Function which creates content of each hobby element
var chooseHobby = function() {
  $(this).addClass('hobbyOnClick').removeClass('hobby firstInLine');
  $('.hobbyImg').hide();
  $('.cancel, .sportImg, .sportText').show();
  $('.sportImg, .sportText').css('display', 'inline-block');
  $('.hobby').css('display', 'none');
  updateHeight2();

};

// Function which close hooby section
var closeHobby = function() {
  alert("function start");
  $(this).parent().addClass('hobby firstInLine').removeClass('hobbyOnClick');
  $(this).siblings('.hobbyImg').show();
  $(this).siblings('.cancel, .sportImg, .sportText').hide();
  $(this).siblings('.hobby').css('display', 'inline-block');
  updateHeight2();

};


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hobby").on('click', chooseHobby);
  $(".cancel").on('click', closeHobby);

});
```

Here is HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Portfolio</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script1.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playball" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
    </head>
    <body>

        <section id="page1">

            <nav>
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li><a href="#page1">Start</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page2">About me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page3">Career</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page4">Interets</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page5">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <article class="startText">
                <p>Hello everyone!</p> 
                <p>I want to present to You my website. You can find here some information about me, my career, skills etc.

                </p>
            </article>
            <img src="img/factory.jpg" alt="factory" class="responsive">

        </section>

        <section class="content" id="page2">
            <div class="hobby firstInLine" id="sport">
                <img class="hobbyImg" src="img/workout.png" alt="sport">
                <img class="sportImg" src="img/runmaggedon.jpg" alt="runmaggedon" />
                <img class="sportImg" src="img/gym.jpg" alt="gym" />
                <div class="sportText"><p>Runmaggedon is my hobby for over a year, it is challenging, hard and the people and athmosphere there is just great. For now my best distance is 24 km in mountain terrain, but it was not my last word! </p></div>
                <div class="sportText"><p>Working out is something that I&#39m doing since studies. It is became the part of my daily routine, I love to work with my body and see physical ad power progress. Gym also help with self-discipline and well-being </p></div>
                <div class="cancel"><p>CANCEL</p></div>
            </div>
            <div class="hobby" id="travel">
                <img class="hobbyImg" src="img/map-of-roads.png" alt="travel">
            </div>
            <div class="hobby" id="objectivism">
                <img class="hobbyImg" src="img/atlas-farnesio.png" alt="objectivism">                
            </div>
            <div class="hobby firstInLine" id="engineering">
                <img class="hobbyImg" src="img/car-engine.png" alt="engineering">                  
            </div>
            <div class="hobby" id="programming">
                <img class="hobbyImg" src="img/programming-code.png" alt="programming">  
            </div>
            <div class="hobby" id="economy">
                <img class="hobbyImg" src="img/hand-holding-up-a-sack-of-money.png" alt="economy">  
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="content" id="page3">
            <h1></h1>
                        <article>

            </article>
        </section>
        <section class="content" id="page4">
            <h1></h1>
                        <article>

            </article>
        </section>
        <section class="content" id="page5">
            <h1></h1>
                        <article>

            </article>
        </section>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please show us your HTML too please? That way we can give you a more accurate answer of what is going wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question

Comment: My bad, html added.

Answer (score 0):

You might be running here into the issue of event bubbling, which is preventing your second event to occur. Here is the link I find most helpful
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/bubbles

Answer (score 0):

We can see that your event is fired. Indeed the alert is working well.

Ok I've maybe find what's wrong here. Be careful with the `.show() and .hide()`. Indeed it will always be over-written by other element in the CSS.

That means that

```
    // Function which creates content of each hobby element
  var chooseHobby = function() {
  $(this).addClass('hobbyOnClick').removeClass('hobby firstInLine');
  $('.hobbyImg').hide();
  $('.cancel, .sportImg, .sportText').show();
  $('.sportImg, .sportText').css('display', 'inline-block'); <!-- This line -->
  $('.hobby').css('display', 'none');
  updateHeight2();

};

// Function which close hooby section
var closeHobby = function() {
  alert("function start");
  $(this).parent().addClass('hobby firstInLine').removeClass('hobbyOnClick');
  $(this).siblings('.hobbyImg').show();
  $(this).siblings('.cancel, .sportImg, .sportText').hide(); <!-- will prevent this line to work -->
  $(this).siblings('.hobby').css('display', 'inline-block');
  updateHeight2();

};
```

Maybe clean your code a little. I suggest you read this link : https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

As I understand your project you could use the `.toggle()` instead.

Maybe try something like

```
// Function which creates content of each hobby element
$('.hobby').click(function ()
{
    $(this).addClass('hobbyOnClick').removeClass('hobby firstInLine');
    $('.hobbyImg').css('display', 'none');
    $('.cancel, .sportImg, .sportText').css('display', 'inline-block');
    $('.hobby').css('display', 'none');
    updateHeight2();

});

// Function which close hooby section
$('.cancel').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().addClass('hobby firstInLine').removeClass('hobbyOnClick');
    $('.hobbyImg').css('display', 'block');
    $('.cancel, .sportImg, .sportText').css('display', 'none');
    $('.hobby').css('display', 'inline-block');
    updateHeight2();

});;
```

If it's not working feel free to ask more :D

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes and now it is working correctly. Here is mo code:

```
var chooseHobby = function()
{
    $(this).addClass('hobbyOnClick').removeClass('hobby firstInLine');
    $('.hobbyImg').hide();
    $('.cancel, .sportImg, .sportText').show();
    $('.sportImg, .sportText').css('display', 'inline-block');
    $('.hobby').css('display', 'none');
    updateHeight2();
};

// Function which close hooby section
var closeHobby = function()
{
    $(this).parent().removeClass("hobbyOnClick");
    $(this).parent().addClass("hobby firstInLine");
    $(this).siblings(".sportImg, .sportText").hide();
    $(this).hide();
    $('.hobbyImg').show();
    $('.hobby').css('display', 'inline-block');
    updateHeight();
};


$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(this).on('click',".hobby", chooseHobby);
    $(this).on('click',".cancel", closeHobby);

});
```